# Is it possible to follow a post in Facebook without commenting or liking?

Tags: facebook, notifications

Is it possible to *follow* a post, or more specifically the discussion on the post, in Facebook without liking it or commenting on it?

By *following*, I mean receiving notifications about any added comments on the post. Not sure if it's the right term.

Commenting does seem to set a discussion as *followed*, and currently I think this can be cancelled for a single discussion from the notification list via the "turn off..." `[x]` extra menu on a notification related to that post. (Not 100% sure about this.)

<sup>Of course with Facebook what's possible today might change tomorrow without notice (which I do consider a good thing), and also during feature releases what's true for one user might not hold for another.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the options arrow in the top-right corner of the post and then choose “Follow”:

[image: Example]